# getBoundingClientRect top property returns wrong value?

Tags: css

I'm getting in console top, left , right, bottom properties of div element:

```
var offSet = document.getElementById("div").getBoundingClientRect();
```

Why do I get **top** 84 px instead of 8px?

Here's an example : https://codepen.io/Y-Taras/pen/zPjrWJ

P.S. to see in the console 4 properties click anywhere at the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CodePen, the script in the body is executed before the onload event is fired. So the info you get from the div (in the global `offSet` variable) is from the position it's in before the `draggable` function has changed the span to position absolute.

(You can see this by, for instance, adding `alert()` in the code just before assigning `offSet`. Then program execution pauses when the div is still below the span.)

Solution: fetch the `offSet` information inside the `onmouseup` function, or in the `onload` event.